# Argument type URL is not assignable to parameter type string

Tags: typescript, url, types, axios

I am trying to perform an Axios request using the URL type. But I get the error `Argument type URL is not assignable to parameter type string`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { NotificationsInterface } from '../interface/notifications.interface'
import { OS, UserType } from '../../global.constants'
const axios = require('axios').default

@Injectable()
export class NotificationsGateway implements NotificationsInterface {
  readonly urlDevices = new URL(
    'https://blablablabla.amazonaws.com/Prod/devices'
  )

  async saveDeviceAuthenticationInfos(
    userId: number,
    userType: UserType,
    deviceId: number,
    pushToken: string,
    operatingSystem: OS
  ): Promise<void> {
    const body = {
      userId,
      userType,
      deviceId,
      pushToken,
      operatingSystem,
    }

    await axios.post(this.urlDevices, body)
  }
}
```

How am I suppose to make it work? I am half a mind to put it back into a string, but I feel like it's a regression.

Comment: Axios expects a string, as the error tells you - you could pass `this.urlDevices.toString()`, or have a facade for Axios that accepts a `URL` (which would have other benefits), but what was the objective in making it a `URL` to start with?

Comment: Well, I am manipulating a URL, therefore it made sense to use this type to be more rigourous. Ain't it the reason to use typescript instead of vanilla JS in the first place ?

Comment: You can use `.toString()` to stringify the url: `await axios.post(this.urlDevices.toString(), body)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says, you're giving a `URL` where a `string` is expected.

If you want to keep using the type `URL` for some reasons, you can do the following: give `this.urlDevices.toString()` as the first parameter of the `axios.post()` method.

Or you can just type your `urlDevices` as a `string` if you're not planning on using `URL`'s static methods.